# Given a geometric random variable, why is it that $P(X > x) = (1 - \theta)^x$ and not $\theta(1 - \theta)^x$?

Tags: distributions, geometric-distribution

Suppose $X$ ~ $Geometric(\theta)$, where the distribution is based on identically independent Bernoulli trials (each trial has $\theta$ = probability of a success). The distribution is for the number of failures before a success (not including the success). The probability distribution is $P(X = x) = p(x) = \theta (1 - \theta)^x$, $x = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$.

Now, I want to calculate $P(X > x)$ (in terms of CDF) where $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$. The answer to this would be $(1 - \theta)^x$ but I am not sure why you don't consider the extra success trial and so multiplying the formula by $\theta$ like in the $P(X = x)$. I get that $P(X = x)$ means "evaluate the probability when the random variable $X$ is $x$, however, I am not sure what it means when $P(X > x)$. What probability are you really evaluating here and of what?

Comment: Look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). Begin by noticing that there are two formulations. In one, the random variable $X$ counts trials 0, 1, 2, 3, ... before the first success; in the other, the random variable counts trials 1, 2, 3, 4, ... up to the first success. Be sure you know which model you are using. // Also notice that you are not asking about the PDF. You are asking about 1 - CDF, // If you clarify exactly what you are asking, you will have a better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @BruceET Okay, thanks, it's edited.

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole $x$ trials?"  Indeed, since the expression "$P(X\gt n)$" doesn't involve any $x$ whatsoever, to what does "$x$" refer?

Comment: @whuber Oh yes, I was confused by that. I will reword the question.